# I have done the second direction of the proof. Hopefully, it is true. Please show my mistakes?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Show that two $C^{∞}$ vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on a manifold $M$ are equal if and only if for every $C^{∞}$ function $f$ on $M$,we have $Xf =Yf$.

I have sone one direction of the proof.

let $p ∈ M$. To show that $Xp = Yp$, it suffices to show that $Xp[h] = Yp[h]$ for any germ $[h]$ of $C^{∞}$ functions in $C^{∞}_{p} (M)$. Suppose $h: U → \Bbb R$ is a C^{∞} function that represents the germ [h]. We can extend it to a C^{∞} function $h : M → \Bbb R$ by multiplying it by a C∞ bump function supported in U that is identically 1 in a neighborhood of p. By hypothesis, $X h ̃ = Y h ̃$ . Hence,
$X_{p} h ̃ = ( X h ̃)_{p} = ( Y h ̃ )_{ p} = Y _{p }h ̃$ . 
Because $h ̃ = h $ in a neighborhood of p, we have Xph = Xph ̃ and Yph = Yph ̃. It follows from (14.1.1) that $X_{p}h = Y_{p}h$. Thus, $X_{p} = Y_{p}$. Since p is an arbitrary point of $M$, the two vector fields X and Y are equal.

I have done the second direction of the proof. Hopefully, it is true. Please can you show my mistakes? Thank you

Comment: I'm confused, isn't there really only one direction to prove?  You just need to show that if $X f = Y f$ for all functions $f$, then $X = Y$.  The converse is that if $X = Y$, then $X f = Y f$ which is obvious.

Comment: Ok I understand the direction I asked. But Is the direction I wrote false? Can you show my mistakes? @muzzlator

Comment: Dear B11, please edit your text: the numerous typographical mistakes are no incentives for users to help you.

Comment: See my solution @B11, I think it is essentially what you are doing but I can't really follow what you are saying so you can see for yourself if you're doing what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ be a coordinate system centred on $p$ and define $f^p_i(x) = x_i$ locally around $p$ and multiply it by a suitable bump function to extend it to a $C^{\infty}$ function over $M$.  Then $Y_i = (Y f^p_i)_p = (X f^p_i)_p = X_i$ and so $X_p = Y_p$ for all $p$.  Therefore $X = Y$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language of germs etc. so you will know better than me.  If you feel as though you're doing something identical to me, then I would agree with your method.

Comment: Well, Is this enough to prove the second direction of the proof?

Comment: Yes, since the hypothesis says $X f = Y f$ for all $C^{\infty}$ functions, we are free to choose the functions we want.  We can use this to show at every point $p$, $X_p = Y_p$.

Comment: Ok thank you dor help :)